# How to change ActionBar Spinner text color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'd like to change the style of this ActionBar Spinner below. It's all about changing the colours of the followings:

- the selected text in spinner header (1. - currently gray)
- spinner drop-down selected text (2. - currently white)
- spinner drop-down non-selected text (3. - currently gray)

[image]

One more thing, it's generated with Android Action Bar Style Generator:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this programmatically :

```
spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourDesign);
spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.yourDesign2);
```

Comment: I'd like to change text colour, not the background colour.

Comment: You can change in your xml ?

Answer (score 0):

This tool (Style Generator) is supposed to help only with the resources (images and xml's) to create custom action bars.

To change text colors, do it directly in the xml of the [Spinner.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) Or, if you're using some kind of third-party component, change it via Java, with an Adapter and its specific configs.

By the way, this plugin [is now deprecated](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-actionbarstylegenerator). Consider using [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) or [its support library equivalent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html).